# py.test test discovery for a test in a file that does not begin test_*.py

Tags: python, pytest

I am new to py.test and want to simply write some test functions next to some other functions in a Python file.

My main file is called something like `myfile.py`.  Inside that file I have a function. For example:

```
def pad(bytes):
    return " "*bytes
```

I want to verify the behavior of the function:

```
def test_pad():
    assert pad(3)=="   "
```

The problem is my `test_pad()` function never runs.  It does run if I put it in a file called `test_myfile.py` and that file does an `import`, but that seems like a lot of overhead.

Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: Tests are generally kept separately from the code - is there a particular reason why you want them to be in the same file?

Comment: Yes. It makes it easier to develop the test and the function that it tests at the same time. I like having the test after the function.

Comment: I agree with Simeon: normally you have the tests seperatly and with measuring the test coverage you will see if you missed some code. Also grouping tests make it easier to create new tests with fixtures/mocks/etc.

Comment: Good point. Should probably do both. Can py.test measure test coverage?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files=*.py
```

See [Changing standard (Python) test discovery](https://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html) for more details. (It's not that obvious.)